# Show div when you click on another one

Tags: javascript

The goal is to show one div when I click on another one. The problem with my code below is that it shows content when the page loads(you can click on a div to hide/show another one), but I want it to be hidden when the page loads(hidden by default). This is what I have now:

```
<div class="r-clickfeature">...click here to show another div</div>
<div class="r-productfeature">something...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.r-clickfeature').on('click', function(e) {
  return $(".r-productfeature").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some css to hide the second div by default is the way to go.

```
.r-productfeature {
    display:none;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE here.](http://jsfiddle.net/DnZ5S/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is faulty. Change it to this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () { // required for jQuery...
      $('.r-clickfeature').click(function(e) { // on click
          $('r-productfeature').slideToggle(); // slide the other div
      });
   });
</script>
```